# Printing postscript file from C#

Tags: c#, printing, postscript

I have an application that creates a temporary postscript file.
After it runs its main routines, it tries to print the file.  However, when I send RAW data to the printer, nothing comes out.
I've also tried the `PrintDocument` class using this example from the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and that prints the postscript code instead of the resulting graphics.

Is there a way to print a postscript file from C# or would I have to use an outside program such as GhostScript?

Comment: Does the printer support postscript as raw data?

Comment: I've tried sending the postscript file as raw data, but when I do that nothing comes out. The strange thing is that the printer is set up to take raw data. I've used [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322091) to print raw data to other printers successfully.

Comment: If other printers are able to print it, I think the printer you are using now doesn't support postscript. May I know what is the printer model and brand?

Comment: It's a Ricoh Aficio MP 3352. I've tested it with GhostScript and it prints fine using that. I was just looking for another way to do this that doesn't require the installation of GhostScript on all machines.

Comment: http://www.ricoh.com.my/about/prodsummary.aspx?pid=99&aid=183 It seems that your printer supports Postscript. But I'm not really sure what does the "Option" mean. Just to clarify again, other printer works except Ricoh Aficio MP 3352?

Comment: The thing is that this printer is on a print server that isn't within our domain.  So I've set up a redirected port using RedMon to point to the program I wrote which then tests to see if a user is authenticated to the domain on which the printer is located.  The program works with all printers in our domain when I send raw data.  However, using the same method of sending raw data, the printer in the other domain doesn't actually print any output.  Not even a blank page.

Comment: Does it show any error message? Are you able to manually print by using the different domain printer? (Just to make sure it's connected)

Comment: When not authenticated it doesn't show any error message at all. If you are authenticated it will show a prompt asking for a release key. When printing manually to the printer everything works fine. It's just when I try sending raw data from the program that nothing comes out. I've used GhostScript from within the program and when I do that everything works normally as well.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/17216633/57094