# Print a postscript document in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, printing

I want to print a postscript document in VB.NET. So here's how my program works. I am using [Printer++](http://www.printerplusplus.com/) to capture a print job. It gives me a postscript document. I do some modifications to it. Now I want to print the postscript document that Printer++ exposes. The code is below.

```
Namespace XPrintSticker
  Public Class Processor Implements PrinterPlusPlusSDK.IProcessor

    Public Function Process(ByVal key As String, ByVal psFilename As String) _
                      As PrinterPlusPlusSDK.ProcessResult Implements PrinterPlusPlusSDK.IProcessor.Process

        //Do Abracadabra on psFileName poscript file
        Dim dialog As System.Windows.Forms.PrintDialog

        dialog.Document= ?? (Print psFilename)

      End Function
   End Class
End Namespace
```

How do I print postscript document?

Also how can I get a list of printers on the system and silently send the document to the printer without using printdialog?

Comment: Check this link [Send Postscript Document to Printer using VC++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17078852/send-postscript-document-to-printer-using-vc)

Comment: This is Visual C++. I need this in either VB.NET or C#.net VC++ has significantly different API. Plus the printer++ sdk won't work in that. I am sure there is a postscript document hidden somewhere

Comment: I know, but the native methods are the same. Check this: [How to send raw data to a printer by using Visual Basic .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322090). BTW, when using a [`PrintDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument.printpage(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll need to do all the painting yourself.